# 14.04 - What's with systemd-udevd? Heavy CPU and RAM usage when system idle w/o any application running

Tags: 14.04, cpu-load, memory-usage, systemd, system-monitor

I have left my laptop on overnight for charging two video recording devices via USB. Next day I woke up, I found that there was heavy CPU, ram, and swap usage
[(screencap for reference)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wr33w_j8EpVk1ZellLN09wRzQ).

[In System Monitor, I saw that two systemd-udevd processes (see screencap)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wr33w_j8EpTGd0RW5HZjFUWms) were running in the background. What could be the potential causes?

Comment: I have the same problem in CoreOS alpha version, v829.0.0